# How to detect the horizon when using homography with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, homography

I'm trying to create a tool that maps from pixel coordinates on an image (row / col) to actual geo coordinates (lat / long). Creating the homography matrix to do this transformation is easy enough (you can think of geocoordinates as a camera perpendicular to and facing straight down at the earth), but dealing with the horizon is a little more difficult. When using the homography matrix to map from pixel coordinates to actual geocoordinates, I want to be able to tell if the pixel coordinates cannot be mapped and that the transformation is not valid. As far as I can tell point directly on the horizon get projected to infinity and points above the horizon get projected BEHIND the camera. Is there an efficient method to detect these bad projections? Thanks!

Comment: Is this possible? The horizon is an artifact of a spherical earth and homographies only map two planes. If you're viewing the horizon, at some point there are no more pixels; this doesn't happen with planes. Maybe you could set a threshold where some fixed geodesic distance gets mapped to less than a pixel, at which point you call that the horizon (e.g. if 1km on the earth gets you less than 1px distance, you can call that pixel location the horizon)?

Comment: I see that makes sense. Seems like some kind of check would need to be hardcoded. Why would points above the horizon be projected behind the camera? Also do you know if there are other techniques that would help with my problem (mapping pixel coordinates to geo coords)